# Is it possible to create program with python and also run it on iPhone?

Tags: python, ios, swift, python-3.10

create an app with python and then I can create a mobile app with it to run on iPhone or more?

Comment: What do you mean, what do you want to do with python, is it the app itself, or Is it the backend API you wanna build in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replit](https://replit.com) (an online ide) to write code online, or use the replit app, but I'm not sure if there is an app for ios

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## Mobile development

Python doesn’t have built-in mobile development capabilities, but there are packages you can use to create mobile applications, like Kivy, PyQt, or even Beeware’s Toga library.

- `Kivy` - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps. Kivy does not attempt to use native controls or widgets. All of its widgets are custom-drawn. This means that Kivy applications will look the same across all platforms. However, it also means that your app’s look and feel will differ from your user’s native applications. This could be a benefit or a drawback, depending on your audience.
- `PyQt` - is a set of Python bindings for The Qt Company's Qt application framework and runs on all platforms supported by Qt including Windows, macOS, Linux, iOS and Android. PyQt6 supports Qt v6, PyQt5 supports Qt v5 and PyQt4 supports Qt v4. The bindings are implemented as a set of Python modules and contain over 1,000 classes.
- `Toga` - is a Python native, OS native, cross platform GUI toolkit. Toga consists of a library of base components with a shared interface to simplify platform-agnostic GUI development.

## References

1. [Build a Mobile Application With the Kivy Python Framework](https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/#:%7E:text=Python%20doesn%27t%20have%20built,in%20the%20Python%20mobile%20space.)
2. [What is PyQt?](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro)
3. [Toga](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)